# Running Sum by SKU by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been currently working with this code, attempting to retrieve the total cost dollars we hold (inventory reconciliation) of any product by day:

```
SELECT dates.Date,
  COALESCE(ledger.Cost,0) as Cost,
  SKU,
  Description,
  SUM(COALESCE(Cost,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date)
  from dates
  LEFT JOIN ledger ON ledger.[Posting Date] = dates.Date
```

I did join the ledger table with a date dimension in order to have all days in the output (i.e: the ledger doesn't have transactions everyday of the calendar). The challenge is **I would like to have the total cost dollars held by SKU by day** even though there wasn't a transaction in the ledger table for that specific calendar date. (e.g: I'm trying to get how much dollars worth of product we hold today for every SKU and the only SKUs displayed for today are the ones which have posted transactions today. Whereas the other ones are displayed but in its last posting date of transaction in the ledger)

This is a sample of the result of the SQL statement:

```
    Date    Cost          SKU   Desc    Running Sum
2/7/2020    $27,451.38    1     a   $11,915,183.80 
2/6/2020    $109,784.62   1     a   $11,805,399.18 
2/5/2020    $179,860.36   1     a   $11,625,538.82 
2/5/2020    ($3,713.73)   2     b   $373,587.93 
2/4/2020    $106,539.44   1     a   $11,518,999.38 
2/4/2020    ($3,713.73)   2     b   $377,301.66 
2/3/2020    ($104,303.18) 1     a   $11,623,302.56
```

Since there is no transaction for Item #2 in Feb 7th, it doesn't shows in the query for that specific date. I would like to have also a row for item #2 in Feb 7th, displaying its total amount held in the latest transaction date (which is Feb 5th with $373,587.93)

Comment: Can you show some example data, and expected output?

Comment: @Jamiec I put an example on how the query's data looks like

Comment: What table holds the entire list of SKUs? Can you query that table and then left outer join the other two tables?

Comment: Your query looks to me like it should work.  Can you provide the example data from the Ledger table that results in your example output?

Comment: Example input data *as text, not images* and example output data will help you get a better answer, quicker

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method uses `apply`:

```
with q as (
      SELECT d.Date, COALESCE(l.Cost, 0) as Cost, SKU, Description,
             SUM(COALESCE(Cost,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date) as sumcost,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sku, Description ORDER BY d.Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dates d LEFT JOIN
           ledger l
           ON l.[Posting Date] = d.Date
     )
select v.dte, q.cost, q.SKU, q.description, q.sumcost
from q cross join
     (select max(date) as maxd from dates) dmax cross apply
     (values (1, q.date), (2, dmax.maxd)) v(which, dte)
where v.dte < dmax.maxd or
      (which = 2 and seqnum = 1);
```

However, if you want *all* missing dates for each ledger, then this is simpler:

```
  SELECT d.Date, COALESCE(l.Cost, 0) as Cost, SKU, Description,
         SUM(COALESCE(Cost,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date) as sumcost
  FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT SKU, Description FROM ledger
       ) sd LEFT JOIN
       ledger l
       ON l.[Posting Date] = d.Date AND
          l.SKU = sd.SKU AND
          l.Description = sd.Description ;
```